# discord.py Bot doesn't respond when I send a number. Part of a guess the number game

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I need help with Discord.py

I tried to create a guessing game. The bot creates a random number between 1 and 20 (including 20), and then you try to guess it in 6 or less than 6 tries. When you send a number, it will tell you if thats too high/low.

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def guessnumber(ctx):

    user = ctx.author

    await ctx.send(f"Hello {user}! I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You are given 6 tries to find the number. Good luck!")
    secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)

    for guessesTaken in range(1,7):
        guess = int(input())

        if guess < secretNumber:
            await ctx.send("Your guess is too low")
        elif guess > secretNumber:
            await ctx.send("Your guess is too high")
        else:
            break
    
    if guess == secretNumber:
        await ctx.send(f"GG! You correctly guessed the number!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Nope, sorry, you took to many guesses. The number I was thinking of was {secretNumber}")
```

However, when I send the command, it will send the beginning part, but when I send a number, it won't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` function is for `console` input, not Discord. To await a message in Discord, use `client.wait_for()`:

```
message = await client.wait_for("message")
```

You can also write a `check` function to check if the message matches your conditions:

```
def checkfunction(message):
    return message.author == ctx.author and ctx.channel == message.channel and message.content.isdigit() 

message = await client.wait_for("message", check=checkfunction)
```

If the checkfunction returns True, the code will continue, else it will wait for another message.
You can now implement this into your code:

```
@client.command()
async def guessnumber(ctx):

    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.name}! I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You are given 6 tries to find the number. Good luck!")
    secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)

    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel  and message.content.isdigit()

    for guessesTaken in range(6):

        guess = int((await client.wait_for('message', check=check)).content)

        if guess < secretNumber:
            await ctx.send("Your guess is too low")
        elif guess > secretNumber:
            await ctx.send("Your guess is too high")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"GG! You correctly guessed the number in {guessesTaken + 1} guesses!")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Nope, sorry, you took too many guesses. The number I was thinking of was {secretNumber}")
```

You can find more about the `client.wait_for()` function [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for).